# Keep a div as last child of its parent even after any new div is appended to its parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello i am quite struggling with a problem. The structure is like :-

```
<div class="parent" >
    <div class="child1" >
    </div>
    <div class="childToBeKeptLast" >
    </div>
</div>
```

After insertion of new child

```
<div class="parent" >
      <div class="child1" >
    </div>
     <div class="child2" >
    </div>
    <div class="childToBeKeptLast" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Thus I always want to keep my child with class "childToBeKeptLast" as last child no matter how many insertion take place in the parent div.How to achieve this by css or jquery ??

Any help will be appreciated ... Thank you ...

Comment: Do you own the code that is doing the inserting?

Comment: take a look at jQuery's [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method. This adds elements __before__ the one you selected, so you can prepend to the `childToBeKeptLast` div.

Comment: CSS has nothing to do with the ordering in your markup. Is the actual question how to visually keep one element "last", or to actually affect the structure of the markup (always inserting new elements at `children.length-1`)?

Comment: It's *really* worth your time to read [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It only takes an hour or two, and pays you back that time very, very quickly indeed.

Comment: Sorry for the Late reply.. My divs are being formed dynamically. Hence I **don't Know the className**. I am well versed with  insertBefore method.The use case is that -- I dynamically have to append child div to the parent on some event .. and on a particular event i have to append the div as the last child of its parent  which should remain last thereafter always. Thus the last child  can be added **before** other child are added to parent or **after** other child are added  and also all is done dynamically..  @n8wrl: I didn't get you ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) at this context,

```
$('.child2').insertBefore('.parent .childToBeKeptLast');
```

So the above code would insert the new children before of the element which is having the class `childToBeKeptLast` and which is the descendant of the element with the class `parent`

Answer (score 2):

**For Info**, in CSS with young browser, the flex model can help you to keep one last  .. seen at screen:**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GlntC)**

BASIC CSS needed :

```
.parent {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.childToBeKeptLast {
  order:1;
}
/* for demo, make some content*/
div:before {
  content:attr(class);
}
```

The `:not()` selector works **[too](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ihFsy)** *if you want somehow filter some browsers*

```
:not(.childToBeKeptLast) {
  order:-1;/* puts anything that has not this class up in front */
}
```

HTML of demo:

```
<div class="parent" >
    <div class="child1" >
    </div>
    <div class="childToBeKeptLast" >
    </div>
      <div class="child1" >
    </div>
      <div class="whatever clss wich is not meant to be last seen" >
    </div>
      <div class="child1" >
    </div>
      <div class="child1" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this does not do anything do the DOM, div remains where it is in the code of your page.

Answer (score 0):

You also use:

```
$('.childToBeKeptLast').before('<div class="child2"></div>');
```